# Change the value of a checkbox inline using the onChange attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, w3c

Am I doing this wrong or is this impossible? I want to set the value of the checkbox to "0" if unchecked, and "1" if checked

```
<input type="checkbox" onChange="function() {$(this).val(this.checked? '1': '0')};" />
```

NOTE: I know how to do it outside of the `onChange` event or by doing `onChange="takeCareOfThis()"`, I'm looking to do it all inline

Comment: `<input type="checkbox" onChange="$(this).val(this.checked? '1': '0');" />`

Comment: Don't put the logic in a function block. However, the point of setting the value if the element is checked or not seems completely redundant.

Comment: I hear you @RoryMcCrossan, it would take too long to explain why, but I do need it here

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You just need to set the statement to be executed.

```
<input type="checkbox" onChange="$(this).val(this.checked? '1': '0');" />
```

Comment: Oh wow, I was so close yet so far away haha! Thanks! I can accept your solution in 8 minutes only :)